# Node.js express res.download and res.attachment don't changes filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

express 4.13
node.js 5.7.0

I am trying to make resposne to user with renamed file.

```
Archive.findById(req.params.id, function(err, file) {
    res.download(file.path, "justfile.docx");
});
```

This code doesn't working. When i use it, file downloaded with default name, not with "justfile.docx".

Comment: Is the URL being requested by a regular browser?

Comment: Yep. Chrome.
router.get('/download/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
        User.findOne({email: req.cookies.user_email}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return;
            Archive.findById(req.params.id, function(err, file) {
                
                res.download(file.path, "justfile.docx");
            });
        });

});

Comment: As an aside: what's the purpose of finding a user if you don't do anything with the result? Also, what's the value of `file.path`?

Comment: It's a prototype. I'll check user's access to file.
file.path looks like "F:\\uploads\\filename.docx"

Comment: I'm not sure if a browser is allowed to ignore the proposed filename, although a quick test works out just as expected for me (the proposed filename is used by Chrome, not the original filename). It's being saved as `filename.docx` for you?

Comment: Yep. I want it to be saved as justfile.docx, but it is saving as filename.docx

Comment: If you check the response headers, what does `Content-Disposition` contain?

Comment: Nothing. 
And res.set or res.attachment don't work.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, unless you have some sort of middleware that is stripping headers or something (or overwriting `res.set`).